# Problem connecting .NET Client to Neo4j Desktop version 4

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I've just installed Neo4j Desktop, and I am trying to connect using .NET Client, the problem is that when I try to connect I get the Error 404 response (resource not found).
The current situation is as follows:

1) I've created a new user (admin, with administrator rights), to replace the use of neo4j user (I don't have the password for this user).

2) Using admin user I can connect successfully to Neo4j using a browser, so the user seems ok.

3) I have a database running under the Neo4j default database, I can query this db from browser interface, so also db seems ok.

4) In my .NET application I've just put the connection commands present in all .NET Clients example:

**var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "admin", "admin");
graphClient.Connect();**

The execution of Connect generate an exception for resource not found (404).

The current version of Neo4j is 4.0.3, the version of Noe4jClient is 3.1.0.6 (the latest NuGet package found), my suspect is that client version 3 is not compatible with Neo4j version 4.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the `GraphClient` is not able to work with a `4.x` database at the moment, you *can* use the `BoltGraphClient` - but you need to provide a driver instance to it to get it to work due to a change in the way Encryption works with `4.x`.

```
//First create a 'Driver' instance.
var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo"), Config.Builder.WithEncryptionLevel(EncryptionLevel.None).ToConfig());

//Pass that driver to the BoltGraphClient
var bgc = new BoltGraphClient(driver);

//Connect.
bgc.Connect();
```

Comment: Thank you Chris, unfortunately there are still some problems in you solution proposal:
1) If I include only the namespace Neo4j.Driver I get an error because is missing the definition of BoltGraphClient
2) If I include also namespace Neo4jClient (should not needed I guess, but I've tried anyway), the definition of BoltGraphClient is found but then we have a problem with driver: "Type IDriver is defined in a assembly not referenced...."
So it seems there are something strange in this packages, I suppose BoltGraphClient should be present in the Neo4j.Driver namespace but is not.

Comment: You need `using Neo4j.Driver.V1` when you pull the `Neo4jClient` library from nuget, you'll see it will also bring in `Neo4j.Driver`

Comment: I think V1 doesn't exists anymore, this is a comment found in GitHub of the driver:

- v1 is removed from drivers' package name. All public APIs are under the namespace Neo4j.Driver instead of the old Neo4j.Driver.V1.

I can confirm that I cannot find any Neo4j nuget pack with .v1, and "using Neo4j.Driver.V1" is not available in the nuget package I have (the latest version 4.0.1).
Any suggestion?

Comment: you've updated the packages, but Neo4jClient doesn't work with the 4.0 drivers. when you just get the client it will pull down 1.7.x you need to use that

Comment: I could not get this to work either, even with the Neo4jClient 1.7.x

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure what else to suggest, as I've got a quite a few basic examples of this, is there a way you can get a sample to me that isn't working? a gist maybe?

Comment: my conclusion is that to use Neo4jClient with Neo4j version 4.x we need to wait the release of the new version of the client.

Comment: Can you send me an example? the older client does work, I've done it and I know others who have, if you can send me something I can test and see. add it as a bug to the repo with the project and I'll test it!

Comment: @ChrisSkardon  - I assume there are still compatibility issues with version 3.2.0.1 of the client against 4.x databases?

Comment: @MartinGrundy - depends - you can't use it against a different db, so multi-tenancy doesn't work - but otherwise I've not been given a code example that doesn't work. I'm at a loss to what needs to happen - you can also try the `4.0.0.6` prerelease if you want

Comment: @ChrisSkardon - I was using version 4.0.4 Enterprise of the local database and v3.2.0.1 of the client.
Essentially I could not connect at all with a simple

`var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data/"), "neo4j", "password");
            graphClient.Connect();`

Moving the DB to an older v3.5.19 Enterprise works fine. I noticed on one of your posts you suggested using curl to identify the endpoints and they dont appear the same as the older version and return a 404 on the above code (302 found with curl).

Comment: @MartinGrundy - Yes, the default `GraphClient` won't work - the `4.x` version does connect, but I've not fully checked it yet, in _theory_ it should be fine for the `GC` 
4.x of the DB shifted the 'discovery' to the root, instead of `/db/data` which is annoying